# Movie with a type of spy/super hero girl who has to traverse a city full of metal spikes

Tags: story-identification, movie

Movie centred around a type of spy/super hero girl. I can’t recall if she was Asian, but she looked a lot like Trinity from *The Matrix*, I think. Futuristic vibes. The city was full of small, silvered metal spikes, like nails, that were all over the floor and walls; she had to walk over them.

From what I remember, the movie had no dialogue, but I watched it as a kid in maybe 2006-9, so I could be wrong. I don’t remember any of it, I just recall the spiked city, and the impression it left on me of seeing her walking and running over them.

The one posted below might have to suffice. It's similar to what I recall. However, if any one remembers similar ones, could be a lower budget, less commercial, and was centered on the main, lonely individual.
The film was much quieter, and I believe the one below has far too much action. The title of the film could be one word.

Answer (score 2):

Might this be ***[Æon Flux](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0402022/)*** (2005)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86on_Flux_(film)):

> *Æon Flux* is a 2005 American science fiction action film based on the animated science fiction action television series of the same name created by Peter Chung, which aired on MTV from 1991 to 1995. It was directed by Karyn Kusama, written by Phil Hay and Matt Manfredi, and produced by Gale Anne Hurd, David Gale, Gary Lucchesi and Greg Goodman. The film was produced by MTV Films, Lakeshore Entertainment, Babelsberg Film Studio and Valhalla Motion Pictures. It stars Charlize Theron as the title character, Marton Csokas, Jonny Lee Miller, Sophie Okonedo, Pete Postlethwaite, and Frances McDormand.

It's about the right age, and includes a largely dialogue-free scene where the main character -- who does resemble Trinity -- has to traverse an area with metal needles protruding from some sections of the ground.

You can view the scene in question in the video below, beginning at around the 0:42 mark.

Comment: Don't settle for or accept an answer if you don't think it's correct. If there are other similar movie scenes out there, I expect more examples will be posted, but it could take a few hours or days. Perhaps longer, if the film in question is very obscure.

Comment: I'll take a look at this one to see if there are any more visual cues that trigger my core memory. Nonetheless, I'm thankful.

Comment: There was also an animated series that aired, I believe, on MTV.

Comment: I've often wondered - you often seen in action movies people flipping over and over to make progress and - apparently - to avoid the opponent's weapons/avoid accurate targeting - [as seen in that clip here](https://youtu.be/N0vdoedZu8o) - that doesn't actually work, right?  I mean, it's just to look cool in the movies.  Especially when women do it.  Right?